# Sync mysql databases to master server

Tags: mysql, database, replication, synchronization

I need to do a database synchronization from each store to central store. Each store employee should be able to do this sync once or twice a day, due ISPs unavailability here. Owner would check at night, the movements from each store (sales, stock, etc.)

1. I'd use one db for each store (any better approach?)
2. I use common mysql 5, should I use enterprise/cluster or another version for this?
3. Any guides / tutorials?

Software is being developed with a php/mysql framework in lamp environment, and we were not given/assigned budget for licensing other software. Is there still any possibilities?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use Maatkit's mk-table-sync: http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html

Cheers

Comment: I saw that website, but quickly, I guess I'll have to read entire docs to learn it. Thanks